# List box Items as checkbox

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a list box whose items are represented as check box as under

```
        <ListBox Height="237" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The itemssource is assigned in the code behind

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = names;
```

The GUI displays correct number of check boxes but with no text. How can I put the "content" of the checkboxes as in my itemssource  of the listbox1?

Also how can I retrieve which checkboxes the user has checked in code behind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add binding to Checkbox like

```
<ListBox Height="237" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Margin="0,10,0,0" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content={Binding}>
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And when u need to get checkcbox which is checked hook `Checked` event in XAML like

```
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Content={Binding} Checked="OnChecked" Unchecked="OnUnchecked">
                    </CheckBox>
                </DataTemplate>
```

code behind: in that case sender is your `CheckBox`
private List _checked;

```
    private void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
             _checked.Add((CheckBox)sender);
          }
private void OnUnchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
             _checked.Remove((CheckBox)sender);
          }
```

Comment: Thanks that works. Is there a way to find the items checked by the user?

Comment: but that works only when check event is fired. Is that what he wants? People dont use that for listBox. They might want to loop over and find the checked items i guess.

Comment: I think when checkbox is checked he can store it in i.e. List<CheckBox> and when is unchecked, remove from list. Or ?

Comment: If you are using binding and MVVM pattern then you can use linq to get the checked items from datasource collection

Comment: Or just create class which has string property for the content and boolean IsChecked and when checkbox is selected set this property or bind it to checkbox IsChecked proeprty and foreach source for checked objects

Comment: If not custom control, then you hav to add class and bind the properties. I've done that in my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="ListBoxItem">
               <CheckBox Content="{Binding name}" IsChecked="{Binding isChecked}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<MyListBoxItem> names = new List<MyListBoxItem>();
        names.Add(new MyListBoxItem("salim", true));
        listBox1.ItemsSource = names;
    }

    void getCheckedNames()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (((MyListBoxItem)listBox1.Items[i]).isChecked)
            {
                // Do things..
            }
        }
    }

    class MyListBoxItem
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }

        public MyListBoxItem(string name, bool isChecked)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.isChecked = isChecked;
        }
    }
```